# Do dual supply voltage buffers with dual outputs exist?

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, dual-supply

I need a dual voltage supply (+-15V) voltage buffer for my design. This component will receive a signal (varying from -10 to 10V) and transmit it with gain=1 (line driver, voltage buffer or voltage follower) to its output (at least +-10V output).
I am trying to find this component but I can't find anything. Does this type of buffer exist? I can find dual supply ones but no with output in the negative and positive range. I don't know if it is a concept mistake or something.

Comment: Why doesn't an opamp with dual supplies & configured for unity gain not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: @brhans I don't know if the output will be able of varying from -10 to +10V

Comment: Choose an opamp which can drive its output to +/-10V with a +/-15V dual supply. Pretty much any unity-gain-stable opamp can do that ... even the prehistoric 741.

Comment: @brhans thanks. Write an official answer and I will mark it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dual output"?

Comment: Positive and negative values. From -10 to +10V

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use an opamp with a dual package, make sure the opamp can handle a wide supply voltage of 30V and that it is not single sided (dual supply). Common mode range shouldn't be much of an issue because the rails are 5V higher than the signal but check that.